# Asp.net - How to convert a button to a hyperlink

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want a person to click on *purchase*, which triggers code in the code-behind.

This works fine with a `Button`, but I would prefer a text hyperlink?

```
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="purchase" Text="Purchase" />
```

Comment: Ehm so? then you just use <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink> instead ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about a LinkButton? A LinkButton basically gives you an asp:Button styled as a hyperlink.

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="purchase" Text="Purchase" />
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Use a LinkButton instead of a Hyperlink control. It looks like a text hyperlink, but acts like a button.

Answer (score 2):

## LinkButton

**Markup:**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Purchase" ID="purchase"  />
```

**In your code-behind**

```
Private Sub purchase_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles purchase.Click            
  'process order
End Sub
```

---

## HtmlAnchor

**Markup:**

```
<a runat="server" id="purchase">Purchase</a>
```

**In your code-behind**

```
 Private Sub purchase_ServerClick(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles purchase.ServerClick
        'process order
 End Sub
```

[HtmlAnchor ServerClick Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlanchor.serverclick%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)